# How to Sort a Custom listView according to its like value

Tags: java, android

Im new with android studio ,and im trying to develop a app which involve a custom "listview" , is there a way to sort the items by its value?

//"Ex.

1 "Apple"  with 1 like
 2 "Orange" with 3 likes 
 3 "Banana" with 7 likes**

I want to sort it by its "likes value"

Output

1 "Banana" with 7 likes
  2 "Orange" with 3 likes
  3 "Apple"  with 1 like**"

Thank you in advance guys! sample project is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: @Aiexa Alexander enjoy https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/ Pay attention that you have to sort your data before you put it in ListView. Because ListView it's only view to show your data in list representation.

Comment: I've searched github projects which implement same method ,however inside the listview it sorts it alphabetically not by its value (int)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has sortedBy extension function you can use it like below.

```
class Fruit(val name: String, val startCount: Int) 

class FruitsAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<FruitsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var fruitList = emptyList<Fruit>()

    override fun getItemCount() = fruitList.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_fruit, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val fruit = fruitList[position]
        holder.bindFruit(fruit)
    }

    fun updateFruits(newList: List<Fruit>) {
        fruitList = newList.sortedBy(Fruit::startCount)
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindFruit(fruit: Fruit) {
            //Whatever you want
        }
    }
}



class MainActivity: Activity {


    private val adapter = FruitsAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(icicle: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(icicle)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        val rvFruits = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvFruits)

        rvFruits.adapter = adapter


        adapter.updateFruits(/*Your list*/ emptyList())
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , im using java ,is there java codes?

Comment: In java you can use Comparable interface as @Eugene Troyanskii told. Implement comparable interface to fruit class and use Collections.sort method for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Ive solve it by using this ,thank you guys!

````
public class MainActivityCustonlistViewnew extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos;
    private CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
    private ListView customListView;
    private String[] names={
            "3 Khan",
            "2 Ahmed",
            "1 Iqbal"

    };
    private String[] professions={
            "Rank 1",
            "Rank 2",
            "Rank 3"

    };
    private int[] photos={
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_6

    };




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maincustomlistview);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        customListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);
        userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(names,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,this);
        customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        getDatas();
        customListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this, "Name : " + names[i] + "\n Profession : " + professions[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    // getting all the datas
    private void getDatas(){
        for(int count=0;count<names.length;count++){
            userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_option,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText=newText.toString();
                ArrayList<UserInfo> newUserInfos=new ArrayList<>();

                for(UserInfo userInfo:userInfos){
                    String name=userInfo.getName().toLowerCase();
                    String profession=userInfo.getProfession().toLowerCase();
                    if(name.contains(newText) || profession.contains(newText)){
                        newUserInfos.add(userInfo);
                    }
                }
                customListAdapter.filterResult(newUserInfos);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Ive simply added this : ```Arrays.sort(names,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);```